# SpringBoot Admin - Kubernetes - server to override client URL

Tags: java, kubernetes, spring-boot-admin

Question regarding SpringBot admin deployed on Kubernetes.

The SpringBoot Admin server starts fine.

Then, the SpringBoot app (client) starts fine.

The SpringBoot client application correctly registered himself.
(Can see

```
[gistrationTask1] d.c.b.a.c.r.ApplicationRegistrator       : Application registered itself as 32a6bf789a7d
```

in the logs of the client)

However, the server "is seeing a wrong client address"

```
[,9e0816eadf7218f9,9e0816eadf7218f9,true] 47 --- [or-http-epoll-1] d.c.b.a.server.services.StatusUpdater    : Couldn't retrieve status for Instance(id=32a6bf789a7d, version=0, registration=Registration(name=myservice, managementUrl=https://{some wrong IP here}:9010/, healthUrl=https://{some wrong IP here}:9010/__health, serviceUrl=https://{some wrong IP here}:9010/, source=http-api), registered=true, statusInfo=StatusInfo(status=UNKNOWN, details={}), statusTimestamp=2020-11-08T05:15:00.451717Z, info=Info(values={}), endpoints=Endpoints(endpoints={health=Endpoint(id=health, url=https://{some wrong IP here}:9010/__health)}), buildVersion=null, tags=Tags(values={}))

io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: /{some wrong IP here}:9010
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ? Request to GET health [DefaultWebClient]
Stack trace:
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
    at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.throwConnectException(Errors.java:124) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.53.Final.jar!/:4.1.53.Final
```

I can see an IP, in my example {some wrong IP here}. But the IP is wrong, hence the connection refused.

The {some wrong IP here} should be like some POD level IP of Kubernetes, inaccessible.

How can I have SpringBoot admin client register himself with the correct IP (the one configured from the Kubernetes Service)

How can I manually override in the server to a correct IP? I.e tell SpringBoot admin server where the connect health endpoint is?

How can I have SpringBoot admin server discover the client correctly please?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After research, there are properties exposed from SpringBoot Admin to achieve this:

```
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.health-url=https://my-override-kubernetes.com/health
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.management-url=https://my-override-kubernetes.com.com/health
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.service-url=https://my-override-kubernetes.com.com/health
```